# Depth first search through a maze in a matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a matrix:

```
 var matrix = [
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
     ];
```

I need to find a way from the point "start" to point "end" using the depth first search algorithm.

```
var start = [0,4],
    end = [4,0];
```

I can move only in four directions. Up, down, left, right.

I tried to implement this algorithm, but my function does not find a way out of deadlocks. The function does not find other paths.

Perhaps I misunderstood how the algorithm works.

You can find my code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/po5dL9t1/4/) and here:

```js
let matrix = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
 ];

let start = [0,4];
let end = [4,0];
let way = [start];

function findWay(position, prevPosition){

 prevPosition = prevPosition || [-1,-1];

 let left  = [ position[0], position[1] - 1 ];
 let right = [ position[0], position[1] + 1 ];
 let up    = [ position[0] - 1, position[1] ];
 let down  = [ position[0] + 1, position[1] ];

 if( position[0] == end[0] && position[1] == end[1] ) {
  return way;
 } 

 if(checkCondition(left, prevPosition)) {
  way.push(left);
  return findWay(left, position);
 }

 if(checkCondition(down, prevPosition)){
  way.push(down);
  return findWay(down, position);
 }  

 if(checkCondition(right, prevPosition)){
  way.push(right);
  return findWay(right, position);
 }

 if(checkCondition(up, prevPosition)){
  way.push(up);
  return findWay(up, position);
 }  

    way = 'No Way!';
 return way;
}


function checkCondition(direction, prevPosition){

 if(direction[0] > 4 || direction[0] < 0 || direction[1] > 4 || direction[1] < 0){
  return false;
 }

 if(prevPosition[0] == direction[0] && prevPosition[1] == direction[1]){
  return false;
 }

 if(matrix[direction[0]][direction[1]] == 0){
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}

findWay(start);
```

Please help me write the function correctly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and a [mcve]. Please [edit] your question and pinpoint where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- Be clear what you want to return. I suggest that you use `null` to indicate that no path was found, for which you can check easily, because it is a false value. You only want to return when you have found a path. When you go left and hit a dead end, you still wanto to explore the other three directions. Your code returns immediately.
- You must check whether you have already been to a cell or not. It is not enough to pass the previously visited cell, because you might walk in a bigger loop. You could check whether the current cell is already in the path, but a common practice is to make all visited cells inacessible by setting them to 1. Of course, when you track back from a dead end, you must make these cells accessible again,so that other paths might still go there.
- Likewise, you can't just add to the way. When you track back, you must remove the cells from the paths again. Otherwise you'll get an incongruent jumble of a path that even includes dead ends. In other words, when you backtrack, you must reset the state of the program to the state that it had when you entered.
- It might be easier to do the check whether a cell is valid up front and return `null` immediately if it isn't.

So here's a working implementation of the following algorithm:

- Is the cell invalid? If so, return `null`.
- Has the cell been visited? If so, terurn `null`.
- Is the cell the target? If so, return the path.
- Mark the cell as visited and add it to the path.
- Walk into all four directions until you find a valid path. If you find one, return it.
- Clean up by resetting the cell and the path and return `null`.

In Javascript:

```
function findWay(pos, end, way)
{
    if (way === undefined) way = [];

    if (pos[0] < 0 || pos[0] >= matrix.length) return null;
    if (pos[1] < 0 || pos[1] >= matrix[0].length) return null;

    if (pos[0] == end[0] && pos[1] == end[1]) return way;
    if (matrix[pos[0]][pos[1]] != 0) return null;

    matrix[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 1;
    way.push(pos);

    let res = (findWay([pos[0] + 1, pos[1]], end, way)
            || findWay([pos[0], pos[1] + 1], end, way)
            || findWay([pos[0] - 1, pos[1]], end, way)
            || findWay([pos[0], pos[1] - 1], end, way));

    if (res !== null) return res;

    matrix[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 0;
    way.pop();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the best solution! Can I ask one more question? How to change the code if each direction (up, down, left, right) has its own priority? For example, if I can go both to the right and to the left, but the priority for the right direction is higher. I then have to choose between the right and the left.

Comment: In the Clockwise starting from top strategy, the current position marker will select the next step
based on the priorities (top, right, bottom, left) for the 4 steps of the method and (top, top-right, right, bottom-
right, bottom, bottom-left, left, top-left) for 8 steps of the method.

Comment: Call the preferred directions first, because the `||` chain will stop at the first non-null value. `pos[0]` is the row in the matrix and `pos[1]` is the columns, so the program above searches in the order bottom, right, top, left.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Good afternoon! Can I ask you to help with breadth-first search algorithm. I implemented this algorithm as a function. But the function returns all the cells to which it can go. And I need to return only the right way. Please look at my code if you do not difficult. https://jsfiddle.net/2n4v2zjr/

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues with your implementation:

1) Checking for visited nodes. You do have a check that makes sure you don't go back to the node you just came from, but that's not enough. You need to check that you're not returning to *any* previously visited node.

To do this, i would keep an array of visited nodes. Each time you expand a node, add it to that array. Each time you're considering expanding a node, check if it's already in the visitied array. So something like this:

```
let visited = [];

function findWay(position) {
  visited.push(position);
  // Rest of function omitted.
}

checkCondition(position) {
  // Code for checking out of bounds omitted

  if (visited.find(v => v[0] == position[0] && v[1] == position[1]) {
    return false;
  }

  // Code for checking passable vs unpassable omitted
}
```

2) When expanding a node, you're only going in at most one direction; the first direction that happens to be passable. This is because you're returning regardless of what the result of findWay is. A simple fix would be to change this:

```
if(checkCondition(left, prevPosition)) {
  way.push(left);
  return findWay(left, position);
}
```

...to this

```
if(checkCondition(left, prevPosition)) {
  way.push(left);
  const result = findWay(left, position);
  if (result !== 'No Way!') {
    return result;
  }
}
```

...along with similar changes to the other cases.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's so simple. And I still could not understand it.